# Implications of disabling distributed cache in SP2013 on all servers?

Tags: 2013, cache

We have a Sharepoint 2013 deployment where we are running low on memory, and we are not able to allocate more memory for this server any time soon. As a mitigation of this problem, we are considering disabling the distributed cache service (simply using Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance in Powershell). We have done this on a test deployment, but the sharepoint logs still indicate attempted connections to the cache service.

My questions are:

1. What are the implications of disabling the distributed cache
   alltogether, with regards to performance and stability?
2. Is there a way of telling SharePoint to not attempt connections to the distributed cache at all?

The farm consists of two Sharepoint 2013 servers with a separate database server.

Comment: Can you share the farm topology in the question.

Comment: Certainly. I've updated the question.

Comment: How much memory is installed in each of the SP servers and how many clients do you have? One option might be to offload some of the services such as search to another SP server in the farm. Unfortunately I'm presuming that since a RAM upgrade is considered unlikely, there are budgetary constraints that would make such a solution similarly unpalatable.

Answer (score 1):

Distributed Cache is required for SP2013 farms. By default DC takes 10% of memory installed/allocated to a server.

Recommendations: 
1. Validate memory used for DC thru powershell on server in question
2. Resolve all DC errors showing log
3. If virtual server, verify Dynamic memory allocation is disabled
4. Distributed Cache is not required for WFE servers, so validate services architecture is addressed for optimazation in your environment.